# Given two independent success probabilities, what is the chance that Player A beats Player B?

Tags: probability

Given that Player A has a 70% chance of winning against the field, and Player B has a 60% chance of winning against the field, what is the probability that Player A would beat Player B in a head to head matchup?

Additional context (from comments): For some added context, I am working on building a prediction model for athletes competing against each other (for the purposes of gambling). I have raw data that suggests the probability of success each player has against average players. I've tried P(A wins) * P(B loses) + P(A loses) * P(B wins) but that doesn't seem to work. I did some research and think I need to include either normal or logarithmic distributions in the calculation, but get lost in how to apply them. I'm interested in the math behind it.

Would it be possible to make a transitive assumption that the two players' win probabilities are against a common opponent (in this case, it is "an opponent with constant skill level) So, 1) Player A has a 70% chance of winning against Player C. 2) Player B has a 60% chance of winning against Player C. ....Given Player C's playing style/skill level does not change depending on his opponent.... is there a way to calculate the chances of Player A beating Player B?

Comment: I would say $7/13$ wins A, $6/13$ wins B, whatever "winning against the field" means.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: a) What are your thoughts on this problem? b) I think more information is needed to give a definitive answer.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, apologies if this came off as "please solve this for me". For some added context, I am working on building a prediction model for athletes competing against each other (for the purposes of gambling). I have raw data that suggests the probability of success each player has against average players. I've tried P(A wins) * P(B loses) + P(A loses) * P(B wins) but that doesn't seem to work. I did some research and think I need to include either normal or logarithmic distributions in the calculation, but get lost in how to apply them. I'm interested in the math behind it

Comment: Without further information, there is no way of answering.  There are non-transitive games... like rock-paper-scissors... where although against a particular set of opponents a person may perform as well as expected, against a specific opponent they might do very poorly.  Imagine if you will, player A always plays rock, player B always plays paper... "*the field*" picks randomly.  Here, replaying ties, we would have player A and player B both have a 50% win rate against the field, but player A has a 0% win-rate against player B.  This is an extreme case, but similar factors could be at play.

Comment: Would it be possible to make a transitive assumption that the two players' win probabilities are against a common opponent (in this case, it is "an opponent with constant skill level)

So, 1) Player A has a 70% chance of winning against Player C.
2) Player B has a 60% chance of winning against Player C.

....Given Player C's playing style/skill level does not change depending on his opponent.... is there a way to calculate the chances of Player A beating Player B?

Comment: Still no.  It could be anywhere from zero to 100% including anything inbetween

Comment: Another example game... player A has a loaded ten-sided die which always lands on 8.  player B has a loaded ten-sided die which always lands on 7.  "The field" rolls a fair ten-sided die.  The game consists of the players and field rolling their dice and comparing results.  If the player rolled higher than their opponent, they win.  Here $A$ wins against the field 70% of the time, $B$ wins against the field 60% of the time, $A$ wins against $B$ 100% of the time.  Compare this to if $A$'s die was loaded differently, landing on $10$ 70% of the time and $0$ 30% of the time...

Comment: The information of how a player does against the field is not enough information.  You also need to know roughly how the game is played... have an idea of how much variance there is in terms of player performance... and so on.  The end result is that you won't have any way of justifying any guess as to how one player performs against another without having made major assumptions which are in *many* real world examples completely invalid.  You won't know how well $A$ can do against $B$ without watching how $A$ performs against $B$.

Comment: @JMoravitz: I agree in principle with your observations, that is why in my answer, I called it a **guesstimate**. But suppose you had no other data, and you were forced to bet between $A$ and $B$, on whom would you bet ? In real life, we are generally faced with paucity of data, we have to decide on whatever little information we have. I would bet on $A$ though as data on encounters between A and B were gathered, I'd revise estimates accordingly.

Comment: @trueblueanil and if you had someone who seems to win $100\%$ of the time and someone else who seems to win $90\%$ of the time.  Do you have reason to believe it possible for the first person to lose when all evidence suggests to the contrary?  Or do you really think the first person would only have a $\frac{10}{19}$ chance of winning?

Comment: @JMoravitz: If **compelled** to bet, I'd bet on the person with the higher probability of success against the presumably common *field*, that's all I'm saying.

Comment: Generally speaking, you should edit additional details into the post, and not just leave them as comments.

Comment: @Brian Tung: I agree, have added.

Comment: @trueblueanil: That's good, but my comment was directed to the OP. :-)

Comment: A model commonly used in sports is that you consider the two consistent combinations. Given the probabilities here, you would suppose A wins with probability $\frac{0.7 \times 0.4}{0.7 \times 0.4 + 0.3 \times 0.6} = \frac{14}{23}$ and B wins with probability $\frac{0.3 \times 0.6}{0.7 \times 0.4 + 0.3 \times 0.6} = \frac{9}{23}$. But this is just a heuristic, not something you can rigorously prove.

Comment: OP: See also my comment on the answer by @trueblueanil.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4848864/14578

Answer (score 4):

A model commonly used in sports, primarily baseball, is the following: If the winning percentages of the two teams are $p_A$ and $p_B$, respectively, then their probabilities of winning a head-to-head match are

$$
w_A = \frac{p_A(1-p_B)}{p_A(1-p_B)+p_B(1-p_A)}
$$

$$
w_B = \frac{p_B(1-p_A)}{p_A(1-p_B)+p_B(1-p_A)}
$$

For example, if $p_A = 0.7$ and $p_B = 0.6$, we have

$$
w_A = \frac{0.7 \times 0.4}{0.7 \times 0.4 + 0.6 \times 0.3} = \frac{14}{23}
$$

$$
w_B = \frac{0.6 \times 0.3}{0.7 \times 0.4 + 0.6 \times 0.3} = \frac{9}{23}
$$

The idea is that when A and B play other teams, there are four possibilities: both teams win, both teams lose, A wins but B loses, and B wins but A loses. But when they play each other, only the last two options are possible. We therefore condition the probabilities of the outcome of the match to just those two options.

There is a small correction that can be made to these expressions, to account for the fact that a team with a higher winning percentage faces weaker opponents, on average, then a team with a lower winning percentage. The details and empirical data can be found [here](https://sabr.org/journal/article/probabilities-of-victory-in-head-to-head-team-matchups/).

I should emphasize that the formulas above (and the reasoning that lead to them) are *heuristic*. They cannot be proven formally, since one can establish conditions under which they don't hold. However, from a practical perspective, under actual sporting conditions, they seem to do reasonably well.

Answer (score 0):

"P(A wins) * P(B loses) + P(A loses) * P(B wins)" is meaningless.

When $A$ wins, it **means** that $B$ certainly loses, and vice versa.

The problem can't be deterministically solved. Without any further information, all we can do is to build a rudimentary  O.R. model to **guess**timate odds which can be refined as more data is available, especially head-to-head win %
With the very scant data, the simplest model that comes to mind is

Odds in favor of $A = 70:60 = 7:6$,

ie P(A wins) $= \Large\frac{7}{13}$

[The figure above is only to be treated as indicating that the odds favor A, see ADDED material for understanding ]

---

### ADDED

Odds or probability estimated on the basis of such scanty data has little sanctity. But suppose you have no other data, and are  forced to bet between A and B, on whom would you bet ? In real life, we are generally faced with paucity of data, we have to decide on whatever little information we have. I would bet on A though as data on encounters between A and B were gathered, I'd revise estimates accordingly. On the basis of the scant and incomplete data we have (eg we have no data on head-to-head),the only firm assertion I am making is that if I were forced to bet, I'd bet on $A$.

Comment: A common model in sports (as I indicated in a comment to the OP) is that if A's and B's win probabilities against the field is $p_A$ and $p_B$, respectively, then A's probability of winning in a head-to-head matchup is $\frac{p_A(1-p_B)}{p_A(1-p_B)+p_B(1-p_A)}$, and B's probability of winning is $\frac{p_B(1-p_A)}{p_A(1-p_B)+p_B(1-p_A)}$. See [here](https://sabr.org/journal/article/probabilities-of-victory-in-head-to-head-team-matchups/) for a discussion.

Comment: @Brian Tung: On comparing my model with yours, what I seem to find is that mine is more conservative in predicting victory for the better team. But as the link you have given has actually analyzed a lot of data and avers that a good correlation with actuals is there, I guess OP could use your model as a basis. Thumbs up, you could get the question opened and put in your post.