# Given the winning percentages of two teams, how do you calculate the relative winning probability of each?

Tags: probability

Suppose we know the winning percentage of Teams A and B (including the past matches between each other), and let's assume their winning percentage is roughly the probability of winning the next game. Is there any simple way to calculate the relative winning probability where A defeats B (or vice versa) when they take on each other?

My gut intuition is just *adding two percentages and normalizing to 1*, like P(A wins | B is the opponent) = P(A wins) / (P(A wins) + P(B wins)), but I cannot find any mathematical way or (pseudo-)logical reasoning to derive this. Can this be done without history?

Comment: This isn't determined generally.  Say you have three teams.  In scenario I, every game is a coin toss.  In scenario II, $A>B, B>C, C>A$ always.  Assume, for scenario II that each pair is equally likely.  Then in both cases each teem wins a random match (with unspecified opponent) with probability $.5$

Comment: As @lulu points out, this is not determined in general. A *heuristic* that is often used is described in my answer to a similar question [here]https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4517419/given-two-independent-success-probabilities-what-is-the-chance-that-player-a-be/4518228#4518228), with a citation.

Comment: To be sure, in these questions, the matches are always with specified opponents, not unspecified opponents. Nevertheless, you cannot determine exact outcome probabilities.

Comment: I am nominating this as a duplicate of [Given two independent success probabilities, what is the chance that Player A beats Player B](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4517419/given-two-independent-success-probabilities-what-is-the-chance-that-player-a-be)

Comment: If you know the record of all prior matches (not just winning percentage), a more powerful model is the [Bradley-Terry model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bradley%E2%80%93Terry_model).  Just a model/heuristic, that makes some assumptions, which cannot be proven.

Comment: @D.W.: Thanks for the link. I've used that lots of times without realizing it had a name. Do you have a citation or line of reasoning for the claim that it's more powerful?

Comment: @BrianTung, it uses more information, so it can give more accurate estimates -- *if* the model's assumptions apply.

Comment: @D.W. That post was exactly what I was looking for. I was pleasantly surprised that I wasn't too far off, but the method there seems a little more based (even though it's also heuristic). Thank you!